# add new field to existing documents by update in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an `index` with properties defined but in documents there is one property missing while importing from another elasticsearch.

Say, in index the mapping properties are:

```
"properties": { 
    "name": {"type" : ..},
    "address": {"type" : ..},
    "email": {"type" : ..}
}
```

But in documents, one of the property say `email` is missing as:

```
{
    "name": "Wheeler Walker",
    "address": "Texas",
},
{
    "name": "Kenny Rogers",
    "address": "Virginia",
}
```

I have the property `email` defined in `mapping` already.

Now I just need to bulk update these documents so that `email` property has `""` empty value.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic case for [updateByQuery](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html).

Your request body should look roughly like this:

```
{
   "query": {"bool": {"must_not: {"exists": {"field": "email"}}}},
   "script": 'ctx._source.email = ""'
}
```